# having resharper give errors for all unused parameters except on events

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

we want to have resharper complain and show errors every time we have a unused parameter to make sure the developers keep code clean and remove stuff that is not being used

the one area where this falls over is events, because we have a lot of case where you are not using the sender object in the basic pattern.

```
(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

is there anyway to have resharper complain on everything EXCEPT event handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember inspection severity of 'Unused parameter' is set to warning by default, however you can change this to Error in `Resharper>Options>Inspection Severity>Redundancies in Symbol Declarations>Unused Parameter`.

When you start solution wide analysis, these are shown as error.

ReSharper is smart enough not to complain about sender parameter because it is part of the event signature.

I have tried this using ReSharper 5 EAP, so options can have different names in the previous version.